# For an electron arrangement diagram, is it necessary to show the inner electron shells or is it customary to only show the valency electrons?

Tags: bond

[image: an electron arrangement diagram showing covalent bonding between a hydrogen and a chlorine atom. All electron shells of the chlorine atom is shown.]

[image: an electron arrangement diagram showing covalent bonding between a hydrogen and a chlorine atom. Only the valence electrons are shown.]

Which electron arrangement diagram is correct? The one that shows all electron shells or the one that only shown the valence electron shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct: for $\ce{Cl-}$, the inner set of electrons would be implicit, as $\ce{Cl}$ has 17 electrons. The point of drawing these orbital diagrams, especially in a molecular context, is to show the nature of bonds and to show how the octet/duplet rules are being followed.

If you have difficulties in using the second diagram (finding it harder to read or are confused by the similarities in $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{Cl}$), you should use the first diagram.

Comment: First paragraph is good. I disagree with the second. If you try to draw all the electrons for iodide you have a mess.

Comment: @MaxW I assumed OP was just beginning to study chemistry and would find it easier for covalent compounds made from the first 20 elements.